# Django return file as string, not as a file

Tags: python, django, file, download

I try to put statistics in excel spreadsheets in dynamic way, so when

#### excel.js

```
$('.js-excel').on('click', function () {
    $.get(
            '/ajax/stat_excel/',
            {
                'excel': 'loan',
                'date_from': $('#date_from').val(),
                'date_to': $('#date_to').val()
            }
    )
})
```

then

#### view.py

```
output = StringIO.StringIO()
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
        if request.GET.get('excel') == 'loan':
            workbook = loanChart.excel(workbook)
        if request.GET.get('excel') == 'debet':
            workbook = debetChart.excel(workbook)
        workbook.close()

        xlsx_data = output.getvalue()

        response = HttpResponse(xlsx_data, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report.xlsx'

        return response
```

And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, because response be like

> PK�������F��AS]$��w������xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml��[oɑ���W|W+#�>�dx(�{}�%j$�$
>   $������ʞ��8�]C�.��QU���������//�q�����ۛ:�����?|���77��*y�n^<=�}�p�������������y����O���*,���

1. Excel file generates excellent. I can see it, if I don't use StringIO
2. I'm not sure, what I need to use, Mimetype or Content-Type. Can't see any difference. Works exactly the same, no matter which type I write in response.

Where can be my problem?

Comment: Are you trying to load excel using ajax?

Comment: Use a plugin like this to help with downloading files via ajax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: @ShangWang Yes, i am. Is it wrong ta download using ajax?

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita thanks.Found an answer. But not using plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4518775/4498908.

I can't use ajax for file download. But I can:

```
function download(path,val) {
    window.location.href = path+"download.php?val="+val;
};
```