# File won't download with HTTP 200 code

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I want to download a file from the front end. The file is generated in the `TestFlow.generateReport` method.

My code runs until the end but it doesn't download anything. It just prints the data to the `console.log`.

What am I missing here?

My backend controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/flow/generate-report" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void generateFlowReport(@RequestParam("flowName") String flowName, HttpServletResponse response) {
    InputStream resource = TestFlow.generateReport(flowName);
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=report-" + flowName + ".xlsx");
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(resource,response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
        resource.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My frontend code:

```js
 $('.generateReport').click(function () {
    var flowName = $(this).attr('name');
   $.ajax({
        url: '/flow/generate-report',
        type: 'get',
        data: {flowName: flowName},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

I get HTTP status 200

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report-tellerFlow.xlsx
Content-Type: application/xlsx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: I think you cannot do this using AJAX. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518702/how-to-download-a-file-on-clicking-the-name-of-file-using-php

Comment: Does hitting the endpoint directly in a browser download the file?

Comment: Because your are using ajax, the download headers arent used with ajax requests.

Comment: @JMullen yes....

Comment: If I can't use ajax, how can i do this?

Comment: nvm.. did it directly.. <a href="/flow/generate-report?flowName=${flow.name}"

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Type: application/force-download` header might not always work because some browsers/web clients might not support the attachment download.

Try changing to `Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` which is the correct XLSX type and then check the documentation for your browser/web client. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax#9970672) using Ajax to download a file might not won't work in your web client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that an XHR request can trigger a download dialog on the browser. You might want to spawn a new window instead with the download URL - the browser should detect the content disposition and handle the download accordingly.

If you still want to do it with XHR, you need to use Blobs instead - [JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link)